# C++ Way to Conditionally Delete from a Singly Linked List

Tags: c++

To preface, my goal is create a function that given a pointer to a node in a custom linked list, will iterate through the list and conditionally delete nodes as it iterates, fixing potential gaps as they come up and keeping the start node either updated if it is deleted or set to a nullptr if all elements in the list end up deleted. I actually have a completely working version of code:

```
void DeleteObjectsByDoublePointer(Node **pStartPtr)
{
    do
    {
        if ((*pStartPtr)->ShouldDelete())
        {
            Node *toDelete = *pStartPtr;
            *pStartPtr = (*pStartPtr)->next;
            delete(toDelete);
        }
        else 
        { 
            pStartPtr = &(*pStartPtr)->next;
        }
    }
    while (*pStartPtr != nullptr);
}
```

My problem is that I am fairly new to the world of C++ and from what I have been told, pointers to pointers are a bit of a relic from C. I recognize a solution might be a solution, but does anyone have any suggestions how I would rewrite this to be more C++ like utilizing something like references? I just can't seem to recreate functionality in way that better fulfills my requirements and I am having trouble reasoning about why that is.

Comment: Pointers to pointers are no more a relic than pointers. Sometimes a reference will work better, but not always. You cannot change what a reference refers to, so this trick: `pStartPtr = &(*pStartPtr)->next` is impossible with a reference.

Comment: your Node class can use templates (```template <typename T> class Node;```) so it is able to take in different data types (```int, std::string, float, double```) you could also use smart pointers so as to not worry about memory leaks ```std::unique_ptr<Node> head;``` and lastly have a LinkedList class separate from a Node class, also using templates

Comment: The proper way to make this more idiomatic in C++ is to not create your own container types. If, for some reason, you really absolutely need a singly-linked list (instead of, say, a vector), the STL already has `std::forward_list`. It also already has a `remove_if` member function that does exactly what you're asking for. This will also save you from having to mess around with `new` and `delete`.

Comment: On a side note, you should use a `while` loop instead of a `do..while` loop, in case `*pStartPtr` is already NULL (empty list) to begin with.